# How to getting file from FTP server and convert into a file for attachments?

Tags: java, email, outputstream

The scenario is getting a file from ftp server and sending as attachment in email. 
I want to getting files from FTP server using "org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient"
about connection,filename success. but i don't know how to convert into File correctly.

here's my code :

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
byte bytes[]=new byte[1024];
int read = 0;

//connection,filename --success

 StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("MyFiles");
      str.append("-XYZ-");
      str.append(new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").format(new Date()));
      str.append(".pdf");
      System.out.println("getting file --> "+str.toString()); 
 System.out.println("getting stream ftp -->"+ ftp.retrieveFileStream(str.toString()));

InputStream input = ftp.retrieveFileStream(str.toString());
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while ((read = input.read(bytes)) != -1) { --> null pointer line 503
   out.write(bytes,0,read);
 }      
File temp = null;    
temp = new File(str.toString());
Utils.convertByteArrayToFile(temp, out.toByteArray());

public static void convertByteArrayToFile(File outputFile, byte[] inputArray) throws IOException{
    BufferedOutputStream bos=null;
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        bos=new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bos.write(inputArray);
    }finally{
        if(bos!=null){
            try{
                bos.flush();
                bos.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the result is..

getting file --> MyFiles-XYZ-17012013.pdf

getting stream ftp --> org.apache.commons.net.io.SocketInputStream@409db838

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.java.EmailForm.sendEmail(EmailForm.java:503)

Any ideas ?
Thanks
MRizq

Comment: Answered for ftp. update your code what you tried for sending mail.

Comment: What happens if you remove the line `System.out.println("getting stream ftp -->"+ ftp.retrieveFileStream(str.toString()));`?

Comment: Good point, my bad, i called it twice. ftp.retrieveFileStream(); - it works now. thanks Samuel :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better you can use method [RetrieveFile](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#retrieveFile(java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream)).

```
File localFile = new File("/path/XYZ-17012013.pdf");
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(localFile);

boolean success = fTPClient.retrieveFile(ftpServerFilePath, fout);

if (success) {
    fout.flush();
    fout.close();
} else {
    System.out.println("Retrieve failure");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting an input stream back from the FTPClient, so that can't be the cause of the null pointer. My guess is you've forgotten to initialize the byte array `bytes` and it's null.
Also, unless you need to store it elsewhere, you might not need to actually dump the contents of the input stream to a file before using it as an attachment. You can probably create it directly from the binary data in memory.